# Transfer file ownership after moving to new server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, security

We just upgraded to a new server, from Server 2003 to Server 2008. I have several SQL Server database files (MDF and LDF) that I transferred over. I keep getting file ownership errors on every file when I try to Attach the database. I have to open up the Properties window on each file individually, select Continue to transfer ownership, close the Properties window, reopen it, assign Administrators to the file with Full Control, and then Attach.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the TAKEOWN and CACLS command-line tools to do all the files at once:

```
TAKEOWN /F * /D Y
CACLS * /E /G Administrators:F
```

That would get it done.

Comment: "TAKEOWN /F *"did the trick. You, sir, are a life saver! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. TAKEOWN is a great command to know about. It saves time like crazy when dealing with bad permissions...